# Inserting UTF-8 json in mongoDB impossible: "Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character 'x' in string escape code"

Tags: python, json, mongodb, encoding, utf-8

It looked pretty simple:

I have a test2.json file with which contains this first document:

```
{'t_text': "RT @BorisMorenas: Informez vous, suivez l'#Obsinsoumis pour d\xc3\xa9crypter #LeGrandDebat de #Laprimaire my_url", 't_lng': 0.0, 't_lat': 0.0, 't_time': '1480016670347', 't_state': ''}
```

I try to import the json in my db debat_primaire as a collection primaire3 :

```
mongoimport --db debat_primaire --collection primaire3 --file Desktop/twitter_elections/debat_primaire_droite_24_11_16/test2.json
```

Which returns :

```
2016-12-06T16:21:53.709+0100    connected to: localhost
2016-12-06T16:21:53.710+0100    Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character 'x' in string escape code
2016-12-06T16:21:53.710+0100    imported 0 documents
```

I have understood UTF-8 is native for mongoDB, so I am surprised.
Then I realize I don't have any trouble when replacing '\xc3\xa9' by 'é'.

1/ why is the utf-8 data not imported in mongoDB ?

2/ I did not find a library to change all possible UTF-8 characters ('\xc3\xa9') to latin1 ('é'). Stuff like "'\xc3\xa9'.decode('utf-8')" does not work. I moved from Python 3 to Python 2.7 to try it, and other techniques:

```
enter '\xc3\xa9'.decode('utf-8')
```

=> returns u'\xe9'

```
import unicodedata
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u'\xe9').encode('ascii','ignore');
```

=> returns 'e', not 'é'

Any help?

Comment: It's an invalid json...I checked it against the jsonlint website...for example `'t_text'` should be `"t_text"`...the same with the others...

Comment: Hello Hackerman, thank you for your answer! Well simple quote did not seem to be the problem! I just escaped with a backslash every slash and every backslash... and it works!

Comment: Yes, for your json to be valid, it need to be like this: `{
 "t_text": "RT @BorisMorenas: Informez vous, suivez l'#Obsinsoumis  pour d\\xc3\\xa9crypter #LeGrandDebat de #Laprimaire my_url",
 "t_lng": "0.0",
 "t_lat": "0.0",
 "t_time": 1480016670347,
 "t_state": ""
}` .... that is a valid json according to http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @BertdeV Can I check exactly what format your data is in? Does it contain the literal sequences "\xc3" and "\xa9" as shown, or does it actually contain those two unicode code points?

Comment: hello @VinceBowdren it was stored in a .txt which contained these sequences, as shown, yes. I opened it in Sublime Text in UTF8 mode, and in TextEdit: same result. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

So first I changed my simple quotes into double quotes, then I just escaped with a backslash every slash and every backslash... + all double quotes inside a value... and it works!

e.g. :

```
{"t_text": "Europe1: Anna Cabana : \"Devant l\'\\xc3\\xa9cart avec Fran\\xc3\\xa7ois Fillon, Alain Jupp\\xc3\\xa9 a voulu jeter le gant\" \\xe2\\x80\\xa6 https:\/\/t.co\/NxQ9PgffMl", "t_lng": 0.0, "t_lat": 0.0, "t_time": "1480016674682", "t_state": ""}
```